# How to block Whatpsapp, Imo, Viber etc from Microtik router?

Tags: router, firewall

I want to block whatspp, viber or other chat apps as such. I have microtik router with RouterOS in it. But how would I block Viber or whatsapp?

1. If I am to block domain, what's their domain though?
2. If I am to block their port? do they use ports other than 80 and 443?

Comment: Unfortunately, since Mikrotik does not offer paid support, questions about their product line is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

A Mikrotik router can apparently use only IP addresses and port numbers for filtering. You'll need to find out the IP ranges and block them. If the IP range is documented officially you'll need to search the Internet for usable information.

Alternatively, you could filter the DNS resolution (e.g. by setting up a dummy zone on your DNS server) but unless you filter DNS to/from the Internet this can be easily circumvented.

More powerful ("NG") firewalls provide content filtering where you could block by HTTP URL or even category.

Comment: Keep in mind that a lot of these services rely on public cloud infrastructure. Blocking them may lead to many new problems.